# paypal adaptive accounts installation difficulties

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to install paypal adaptive accounts API using PHP.

I have set up the developer account, test accounts and app and tested the parameters via the paypal tool.  Now I need to install the API on our test site.

I have used [How to check if curlSSL is working properly](http://www.nextscripts.com/tutorials/how-to-check-if-curlssl-is-working-properly/)
to ensure I have curl set up.

I followed the instructions [here](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#adaptive-accounts) using the PHP tab.  I am installing without composer so I connected via an SSL client and used the command as instructed.

> curl
>   https://raw.github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/stable-php5.3/samples/install.php
>   | php

However I think this repository has been moved and I tracked it down to [here](https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/blob/master/samples/install.php).

Meaning my command should be

> curl
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/master/samples/install.php
>   | php

I may have found the wrong code because it will not install.
The error output is

```
composer not installed or 'useComposer' is set to false in install.php.
Running custom installation ... 
Downloading adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php - v2.6.106 
Downloading sdk-core-php - v1.4.3 
Generating autoload file

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in - on line 340
```

I have checked the install file and the following lines

```
// Flag to control whether composer should be used for installation
$useComposer = false;
```

confirm that useComposer is set to false which makes me think I have found the wrong install file.

So does anyone know where the correct location is to point cURL?
Or am I doing anything else wrong?  Note the install appears to try to run "custom installation" and fails with a memory error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of this is solved.  The install.php file had been removed accidentally .

So you can run

> curl -k -L https://raw.github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/stable-php5.3/samples/install.php | php

This gave me a further error

> This install script only suppoorts namespace based SDK

So I was directed to a non-namespaced version of of the SDK

> curl -k -L https://raw.github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/blob/stable/samples/install.php | php

I then started to get

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 12582912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in - on line 340

So [goto](https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/blob/stable/samples/install.php) fork the file so that you can edit it and assign at the top.  I was successful with

```
ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
```

This will increase the maximum amount of memory available to PHP to 128 MB for the running script.  It is a temporary setting and will only affect the script it is in.